# Bluetooth cannot be turned on in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, bluetooth

I have Ubuntu 14.04 installed parallel to the mac's ios.
Previously, I remember that the Bluetooth used to work when I tried to connect a Bluetooth mouse to the system. But now, all of a sudden, it is not working. It's settings can be found in the system settings but it is not possible to turn it on/off. 
I checked rfkill and it is not blocked. However, it only shows information about wireless LAN and nothing about the Bluetooth. I also added "rfkill unblock bluetooth" to maybe unblock it but still nothing is happening. 
I am also sure that the bluez is installed completely and is updated.
Can anybody help?

The output of "`lspci -knn | grep Net -A2; lsusb`" is:

```
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM43602 802.11ac Wireless LAN SoC [14e4:43ba] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Apple Inc. Device [106b:0133]
    Kernel driver in use: brcmfmac
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 05ac:8406 Apple, Inc. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 05ac:0273 Apple, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 05ac:8290 Apple, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Thanks,
Regards,
Ali

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2; lsusb` terminal command.

Comment: @Pilot6 Updated

Comment: What is the kernel version? `uname -a`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the 4.4 kernel version to use this device. It can be installed to Ubuntu 14.04 by

```
sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-xenial
```

Reboot after you install the kernel.

This is [the commit](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/git/ubuntu/ubuntu-xenial.git/commit/drivers/bluetooth/btusb.c?id=22f8e9dbf671a2f36d90d3d8723a2a0c5227fa4b) that adds support of new Apple devices.